# C++11 features for generic and meta programming

Tags: c++

Can we say that `auto` and `decltype` are part of generic programming?

Can we say that `constexpr` is a feature for metaprogramming?

Comment: `auto` is just syntactic sugar for "I'm too lazy to write the type myself, compiler please deduce it for me". It doesn't change the *actual* final type - it's the same as if you'd typed it out yourself, just easier. It doesn't enable anything new.

Comment: I suppose you could say yes to both.  `constexpr` makes writing a lot of TMP easier.  Same goes for `auto` and `decltype`.

Comment: `if constexpr` is definitely metaprogramming, but I'm unsure about standalone `constexpr`

Comment: Food makes writing classes easier but that doesn't mean it's a part of OO

Comment: Personally I find food to get in the way of programming and makes the keyboard a mess ;)

Comment: Why does that matter anyway? Is this an interview question?

Comment: I'd say no, no, and no.  Those are core language features that **can** be utilized by generic programming and metaprogramming, but they **can also** be used by procedural programing and object oriented programming.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It is more complicated that that: `auto` (without `decltype` but even that might induce SFINAE) allow to deduce type whereas we don't know the type (as lambda) or is complex to know with overload/promotion `template <typename T1, typename T2> auto add(T1 a, T2 b) { return a + b; }` or `char foo(int); float foo(char);`

Comment: @JesperJuhl `auto` allows unnameable types

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, but for most cases and most users it boils down to "convenient syntactic sugar".

Comment: _"for most cases and most users"_ Only if you're adhering to Auto Almost Always, which you shouldn't ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constexpr` is most useful for metaprogramming, as it permits the compiler to pull certain parts of our code into the metaprogramming world.

That doesn't mean that when you write `constexpr` you are always metaprogramming. I can declare a nice constant `constexpr int x = 42` out of good habits but that doesn't mean I'm metaprogramming.

`auto` and `decltype` relate to types, but they are not part of generic programming. They are part of your general C++ toolkit. Would you see `decltype` predominantly inside templates? Sure, possibly.

I don't think trying to shoehorn things into "boxes" like this is useful, anyway.

Comment: what about "auto" actually being the difference between a normal lambda and a generic lambda?

Comment: I would add [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) as the more important feature of the language for metaprogramming.

Comment: @PeterT I'd argue that the fact we _have_ to use `auto` to "turn on" the templateyness of a lambda doesn't make `auto` a template feature in itself. We have to use angle brackets to declare a template, but angle brackets aren't a generic programming feature.